# How to style part of text string before a symbol

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have text which comes from for loop, for example `"Hello: how are you?"`   and  `"Hi: I am fine"`.

I want to make the text before `:` to be in bold. So above example I need `"Hello"` and `"Hi"` to be bold as they are in front of `":"`

So actually my html is . There is a for loop on node

```
       <div >      
          <a>
            {{node.childrenCount == 0 ? node.code + ': ' + node.name: node.code + ': '+ node.name  + ' ('+ node.childrenCount + ')' }}
          </a>
        </div>
```

How do I do that using CSS?

Comment: What have you tried? Unless JavaScript is an option, there's no way to do this unless the HTML delineates where the separation should occur. E.g. `<span>Hello:</span> how are you?`

Comment: i tried to use css :before and :after , look like that is used only to insert content

Comment: @j08691 can you post your javascript solution. I will see if i can use that

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML and update your tags first

Comment: so what exactly are your constraints? you have ZERO control over the printed text?

Comment: yes i have zero control over printed text.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with CSS without modifying the markup.

If you can modify the template, you could write:

```
<div>      
  <a><strong>{{ node.code }}</strong>: {{ node.name }}</a>
</div>
```

---

(Edit to address ternary in updated question)

That ternary is conditionally rendering the `childrenCount` in parentheses if it isn't equal to `0`, which could be written as:

```
<div>      
  <a><strong>{{ node.code }}</strong>: {{ node.name }}{{ node.childrenCount !== 0 ? ' (' + node.childrenCount + ')' : '' }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think i have to go with this approach. But my template is more complex, i have changed my question. Can you see how i can use your idea here?

Comment: @NoStressDeveloper If this answered your question, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
let str = "Hello: how are you? Hi: Im fine?";
str = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+:/g, '<strong>$&</strong>');
//result: "<strong>Hello:</strong> how are you? <strong>Hi:</strong> Im fine?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strong` tag helps screen readers, but you can also use `b` tag or modify a `span` tag with css property `font-weight:bold;`.

```
 <strong>Hello:</strong>How are you?
```

Comment: its a dynamic html based on variable. so i don't think i can use this

Answer (score -1):

just wrap what you want in < b > tags

```html
<b>Hello:</b>How are you? <br>
<b>Hi:</b> I am fine".
```

Comment: I'm thinking it's not that simple and the OP can't modify the HTML

Comment: yes i can't modify like that. It's dynamic html based on variables